# Get single value from dynamic SQL SELECT

Tags: sql-server

How can I retrieve the value from the following dynamic SQL and assign it to a variable?

```
SET @SQLString = N'SELECT TOP 1 D'+CAST(DAY(@dateTime)AS varchar(MAX)) 
               + ' FROM TabelForMonthCurrent'
               + ' WHERE empContractID=' + CAST(@pEmpContractID AS nvarchar(MAX))
               + ' AND Year=' + CAST(YEAR(@dateTime) AS nvarchar(MAX)) 
               + ' AND Month=' + CAST(MONTH(@dateTime) AS nvarchar(MAX))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your dynamic SQL to `SET @SQLString = N'SELECT @result =`...

Then use [sp_executesql](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx):

```
DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(MAX)
EXEC sp_executesql
    @query = @SQLString, 
    @params = N'@result NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', 
    @result = @result OUTPUT
```